# A futuristic Phobia in the scientific context (Related to Artificial Intelligence)

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice, science, phobias

Is there any specific term to describe a phobia about future of relationship between humans and (intelligent) machines? One may think it could be [Cyberphobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberphobia) or [Mechanophobia](http://www.phobiasource.com/mechanophobia-fear-of-machines/), however these options are far different from what a top scientist such as **[Stephen Hawking](http://www.techinsider.io/stephen-hawking-artificial-intelligence-technology-take-jobs-2015-10)** warns about: "*the development of full artificial intelligence [AI] could spell the end of the human race.*"

No matter how much such a prediction is true and possible, how should refer to that?

Comment: I haven't come across an official term for that as yet and you will most likely have to coin a neologism.

Comment: BTW, what the OP talks about is not "futuristic" phobia, but a phobia of things futuristic.

Comment: If we are going for a neologism, I submit "mechanarchiphobia,"  a fear of being ruled by machines.

Answer (score 2):

Given that Homo Sapien essentially translates to "Wise like us" I think that a new sentience would be labeled as Sapien Superius and as such the ideal term for the unreasonable fear there of would be **Sapiophobia**, a fear of the wise. That is what I think it *ought* to be.

As it so happens there is **[Prosophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosophobia)**,  an irrational fear of progress.

Answer (score 1):

**Technophobia** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/technophobia)

> *noun* fear or dislike of advanced technology or complex devices and especially computers

**Robotophobia** — [Robots and Androids](http://www.robots-and-androids.com/Robophobia.html)

> Robophobia is an anxiety disorder in which the sufferer has an irrational fear of robots, drones, robot-like mechanics or artificial intelligence.
>
> It frequently results in a panic attack and can be triggered by certain stimuli or situations, such as viewing a robot, being near a robot, or even just talking about robots. Some robophobic patients with find their anxiety levels rise when they are near most any autonomous machine, especial human-looking robots. This is similar to fears of luddites, but more specific to robots and AI.

---

Further reading only:

**Technological singularity** is an **existential threat** that someday these machines will turn against their masters (humans). It is a [frequently appearing trope in movies](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TurnedAgainstTheirMasters). The construction "existential threat" is strange because it means ‘threat to existence’, rather than ‘threat that exists’.

> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technological_singularity) — The **technological singularity** is a hypothetical event in which an upgradable intelligent agent (such as a computer running software-based artificial general intelligence) enters a 'runaway reaction' of self-improvement cycles, with each new and more intelligent generation appearing more and more rapidly, causing an intelligence explosion and resulting in a powerful super-intelligence whose cognitive abilities could be qualitatively as far above humans, as human intelligence is above ape intelligence.

<sub>Interesting article: [Stephen Hawking, Elon Musk, and Bill Gates Warn About Artificial Intelligence](http://observer.com/2015/08/stephen-hawking-elon-musk-and-bill-gates-warn-about-artificial-intelligence/)</sub>

Comment: Downvote, wow! :(